# Making a Grid pixel editor in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ipad

I need to make a pixel editor in iPad similar like Microsoft Paint when displaying per pixel of the image, would like some advise on approach :

- Should I make a series of UIButtons stacked in grid fashion in a UIScrollView? (sounds pretty resourceful and laggy), tapping the uibutton will toggle state to display the pixel.
- Should I draw line grids using coregraphic and detect taps using gesturerecognizer (I like this, but need some code samples).
- Or should I look into using UITableView and making use of reusable cells for the editor? (This seems like how apple would advise).

Hope to get some interesting responses!

Answer (score 2):

A custom-drawn view (i. e. Core Graphics) is the only reasonable approach. Anything using multiple views will lag with larger images, no matter if it's `UIButton`s or `UITableViewCell`s.

For a general Core Graphics introduction, try [the official one](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) or [that one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/iOSGetStarted01.aspx).

To draw your fat pixels with a grid, you could either fill the entire canvas with the grid colour, then fill the fat pixels with the respective colour using `UIRectFill()` taking into account the proper grid spacing. Or you could draw the grid lines with `-[UIBezierPath stroke]` and a bezier path that encloses the fat pixel.

Also, for performance reasons you will probably want to respect the dirty rect passed to `-[UIView drawRect:]` so as to not draw regions that don’t need to be redrawn.

Comment: Mind providing some guidance on coregraphic to draw grid lines? I don't really know much about CoreGraphics. :D Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer with documentation links and a suggestion how you could implement grid lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the UITableView. It's way more efficient and easier to do than a grid full with UIButtons.
Yep, CG is the proper way, I think

Answer (score 0):

I think using GridView will be more efficient, ref : [DTGridView](http://danieltull.co.uk/blog/2009/10/28/dtgridview/)

Comment: I tried using DTGridView, it was quite laggy as I load 30x30 grids on the iPad. Also, it have problems with UIImageView and occasional missing cells.